How to update an element in a List<T> object in .NET Core
How can we update  List type and not ADD rows instead of updating. In my below code what I have implemented is that first I have a view which displays LIST of object in a table in editable format. This all works great, however the challenge I am facing is when I make changes to list or say update the list and then click on SUBMIT button. Note here I am not adding a new object, I am simply updating existing object. So may be I will update row 1, row 2 or more than that.
On action perform the method ADDS a new rows instead of updating the existing ones. Here is my code:
VIEW
    <table class="table align-middle mb-0 bg-white table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Defect ID</th>
            <th>
                <label>JobId</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Created date</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label>Created By</label>
            </th>
            
             
             <th>
                ProjectName
            </th>
             <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <form asp-action="Defectlist" method="post">
            @for (var i=0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
                <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(a => a[i].DefectId)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(a=>a[i].JobId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(a => a[i].DefectCreatedDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(a => a[i].DefectCreatedBy)
            </td>
            
            
            <td>
                    <select asp-for="@Model[i].ProjectId" asp-items="@ViewBag.List"></select>
            </td>
            
             @* <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.DefectId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.DefectId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
            </td> *@
        </tr>
            }
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </tbody>
</table>

This is Controller Action
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Defectlist(List<Defect> model)
{
    
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach(var i in model)
        {
            db.Defects.Add(i);        
        }
        db.SaveChanges();
        TempData["SM"] = "Task updated";

        
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Defectlist");

}


Of course, when you Add() to db.Defects, you add new records. You need to find the existing row (by DefectId, possibly?) and update the changed fields. Not that your posted display-only code can update anything...

@HansKeﬆing any suggestions how to achieve this

@Yong Shun any suggestions on this

db.Defects.Update(i);

If you just want to know how to update the row inside this Defectlist method, I suggest you could refer to this official document.
Since I don't know you want to update some column for this Defect model or not, I suggest you could try below codes:
By using this way, it will firstly query the result and just update some column not all column.
Like below:
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          foreach (var i in model)
          {
              var defectToUpdate = await _applicationDbContext.Defects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.DefectId == i.DefectId);

              if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<Defect>(
       i,
       "",
       s => s.JobId, s => s.DefectCreatedDate, s => s.DefectCreatedBy))
              {
                  try
                  {
                      await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                     // return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                  }
                  catch (DbUpdateException /* ex */)
                  {
                      //Log the error (uncomment ex variable name and write a log.)
                      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. " +
                          "Try again, and if the problem persists, " +
                          "see your system administrator.");
                  }
              }
          }
          
          TempData["SM"] = "Task updated";


      }

